# Return of syscall with wrong file descriptor is not negative

Tags: c, macos, assembly, nasm

I write program on c and I need to use functions from assembly.
I think when a *syscall* is facing a problem it returns a negative value and write it to rax, but it doesn't do it.

I use macOS and NASM. To be more precise, my write function is:

```
        global  _ft_write
        extern  ___error

_ft_write:
            mov rax, 0x2000004
            syscall
            ret
```

for compile: `nasm -fmacho64`

and main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int         ft_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);

int         main(void)
{
    printf("%d", ft_write(-15, "wrong file descriptor", 3));
    return (1);
}
```

> expexted output: -9

> my output: 9

I tried to use read only files, but output was 9 too. Were is mistake? Why rax is non negative after syscall error and how can I receive syscall return after error?

Comment: A final `;` is missing on ft_write declaration

Comment: The method for reporting system calls is different from OS to OS. Where did you read that writing a negative value to RAX is what MacOS does?

Comment: So, Mac OS man says only about return value of syscall. That means syscall return it and write somewhere and I thought that it is RAX, but it isn't. May be you know where?

Comment: I don't. Perhaps you can figure it out by disassembling the syscall stubs in libSystem.

Comment: Instead of returning negative rax, the carry flag is set. Check the carry flag.